# Append string and special character in the output of jq command

Tags: json, jq, confluence-rest-api

I have a json file GroupList.json:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "type": "known",
      "username": "USERID1",
      "displayName": "DISPLAYNAME1",
      "_links": {
        "self": "https://confluence.com/rest/api/user?key=123"
      },
      "_expandable": {
        "status": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "known",
      "username": "USERID2",
      "displayName": "DISPLAYNAME2",
      "_links": {
        "self": "https://confluence.com/rest/api/user?key=1234"
      },
      "_expandable": {
        "status": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 50000,
  "size": 2,
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://confluence.com/rest/api/group/GROUPNAME/member",
    "base": "https://confluence.com"
  }
}
```

I'm fetching the username using the below command:
***jq -r '.results | map(.username) | join(",")' GroupList.json > UserNameList.txt***

Output in UserNameList.txt is:
***USERID1,USERID2***

I want to modify the output to be:

***SPACEKEY : GROUPNAME : USERID1,USERID2***

SPACEKEY & GROUPNAME are 2 variables whose value changes in every iteration.

Comment: Did you try using --arg option ? --arg name value

Comment: I did try --arg, but unable to formulate the command to achieve my requirement

Comment: jq -r --arg foo "123" '.results |  map($foo+.username) | join(",")' file.txt > users.txt - This works as I tested it. When you say each iteration then spacekey and groupname will appear for each record within the results collection. Is that what you want ? then perhaps above style be fine ?

Comment: As you mentioned spacekey and groupname is appearing for each record. I do not want them for each record. 
As of now it is like "spacekey groupname userid1"
"spacekey groupname userid2"
I want it to be: "spacekey groupname userid1,userid2"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your file, the following invocation produces the output shown below:

```
jq -r --arg prefix "SPACEKEY : GROUPNAME : " '
   $prefix + (.results | map(.username) | join(","))
' GroupList.json
```

#### Output

```
SPACEKEY : GROUPNAME : USERID1,USERID2
```